# I'm getting an error when doing server-side fetch on the next js app router

Tags: next.js

I don't get an error in npm run dev but I get this error in npm run build. If I type the API url to another remote server instead of localhost, I do not get the error again.
my error:

> Generating static pages (0/18)  =   
> ExperimentalWarning: The Fetch API is an experimental feature. This
> feature could change at any time (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to
> show where the warning was created) TypeError: fetch failed
> at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {   cause: Error: connect
> ECONNREFUSED ::1:3000
> at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
> at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
> errno: -4078,
> code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
> syscall: 'connect',
> address: '::1',
> port: 3000   } }
>
> Error occurred prerendering page "/blog". Read more:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error TypeError: fetch
> failed
> at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11118:11)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) { data: undefined, status:
> 'loading', update: [Function: update] } { data: undefined }  ⚠ Entire
> page /dashboard/login deopted into client-side rendering.
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/deopted-into-client-rendering
> /dashboard/login

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./page.module.css";
import Link from "next/link";
import Image from "next/image";

async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/posts", {
    cache: "no-store",
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch data");
  }

  return res.json();
}

const Blog = async () => {
  const data = await getData();
  return (
    <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Link
          href={`/blog/${item._id}`}
          className={styles.container}
          key={item._id}
        >
          <div className={styles.imageContainer}>
            <Image
              src={item.img}
              alt=""
              width={400}
              height={250}
              className={styles.image}
            />
          </div>
          <div className={styles.content}>
            <h1 className={styles.title}>{item.title}</h1>
            <p className={styles.desc}>{item.desc}</p>
          </div>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Blog;
```

Comment: you haven't handled any thrown errors from `getData`

Comment: throw new Error("Failed to fetch data"); ?

Comment: When you enter another url there, it gets build. The problem is, it doesn't get it from localhost.